# Android Piechart is Empty

Tags: android, view, graph

How can I show a custom TextView if aChartengine Piechart is empty? I noticed that you can not do as a ListView, you have any suggestions?

I display a chart in a LinearLayout:

```
chartContainer = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.chart_container);

// Getting PieChartView to add to the custom layout 
mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(getActivity(),distributionSeries, defaultRenderer); 
// Adding the pie chart to the custom layout 
chartContainer.addView(mChartView);
```

Comment: I suggest to include some of your code in the question.

Comment: I am assuming that you mean, if a PieChartView is not returned from the getPieChartView() method then you want to show a TextView instead?

Comment: Yes, as when a ListView is empty. How can I do?